# Having trouble making this product slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, product

So,i want to make a product viewer kind of a thing having thumbnails which can slide back or front by clicking on the back/front buttons. I dont know why my code isn't working.Heres the code. Please help me out finding issues in it.Thanks!

**Html code**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="main-image">
</div>


<div class='main-slider'>

         <div class="window">
                <div class='slider-large-image'>
                <img src='img3.png' height="500" width="960"> </img> 
                <img src='img2.png' height="500" width="960"> </img> 
                <img src='img3.png' height="500" width="960"> </img> 
                <img src='img4.png' height="500" width="960"> </img>
                </div>    
         </div>

        <div class='slider-pager'>
        <a href="#" id="b"> &lsaquo; </a>
        <a href="#" id="f"> &rsaquo; </a>
         </div>   

</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {



var imagewidth = /*$(".window").width()*/960;
var imagesum = /*$(".slider-large-image img").size()*/5;
var imagereelwidth = imagewidth * imagesum;


$(".slider-large-image").css({'width' : imagereelwidth});

rotatef = function() {



$(".slider-large-image").animate({ 
left : -imagewidth
},500 );
};
rotateb = function() {



$(".slider-large-image").animate({ 
left : imagewidth
},500 );
};

$(".slider-pager a#b").click(function() {
rotateb(); //Trigger rotation immediately
//return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
}); 
$(".slider-pager a#f").click(function() {
rotatef(); //Trigger rotation immediately
//return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
}); 

});
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
 {
margin:0 auto;
 }
.main-slider
{
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:10px;
/*background-color:#CCC;*/
border: 0px solid #000;
top:25px;
left:0px;
z-index:1004;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999;

}
.window
{
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
.slider-large-image
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}


.slider-large-image img {float:left;}

.slider-pager
{
position:absolute;
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 10px;
background-color:#333;
top:0%;
left:89.5%;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:0;
 }
 .slider-pager a 
 {
padding:1px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:700;
color:#ccc;
margin-right:5px;
width:1px;
height:1px;

position:relative;
top:-10px;
 }
.main-slider
{
padding:0px;
color:#FFF;
text-align: center;
line-height: 40px;
font:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.main-slider .slider-pager a:hover
{
background-color:#999;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
color:black;
}
.main-slider .slider-pager a.active
{
background-color:#999;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
.main-slider .info-page
 {
background-color:#000;
width:600px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:#666;
font:"28 Days Later";
color:#FFF;
line-height: 40px;
font-size:40px
 }
 .main-slider .info-page #d:hover
 {
color:#FF0;
  }
```

Comment: Why is this question getting -1? Its a very concrete and straight forward question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start off with your formatting (that I fixed, btw):

1. Your first `<div id="wrapper">` doesn't get closed!
2. IMG-tag is self ending! **WRONG:** `<img src=""></img>` **CORRECT:** `<img src="" />`
3. Some of your css3-variables are for future browsers and -moz-, but is missing -webkit-!! **Example:** `-moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;`
4. Also, at one point you're using ='' and another ="". Its basically okay, but gets annoying to maintain later and doesn't look very clean! Example: `<img src='img3.png' height="200" width="300" />`
5. I did not find any function for `<div id="main-image"></div>` in your provided code. Next time remove these type of elements when your putting together a question here, as this element is 100% irrelevant to the problem at hand. (Same goes for 
    and `.main-slider .info-page #d:hover {}` in your css)
6. Didn't see any reason, why `.main-slider {}` should be declared twice in the css (so I merged them, if you do have special purpose, then put it back like it was)
7. If you are not building some fallback version for some other browser version (like mobile version for example.) Then there is no need to put width="" and height="" variables to your IMG-tag direct. You already had a correct place in css for that: `.slider-large-image img {float: left; width:; height:;}`
8. In your css, you have `.slider-pager a` and `.main-slider .slider-pager a:hover`. Why add `.main-slider` in front of `.slider-pager a:hover` anyway?
9. If you have same parameters for same variable in css, then use comma to merge them: `.slider-pager a:hover, .slider-pager a:active {background-color: #999; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}`
10. Your using `position: absolute;` too much. I strongly believe, you were meaning to use `position: relative;`
11. There was an extra }); at the end of it all. Was the code originally in some function or a plugin?
12. No such parameter as `font`, in css!

**NOTES:**

- You didn't provide the images. Next time please google some images, so it would be quicker to help you.
- Use sites like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), to make good examples of your problem. You might be asking: Why should I waste my time on that? We will ask the same question from you, when we are looking at your examples. This will REALLY make things faster for you are for us, on finding quick and valuable solutions.
- Your code was so messy, that I cant figure out where the element `<div class="slider-pager"></div>` must sit? Its obviously inside the general container (on top of the image,) but at the top, bottom or maybe bottom center? I put it bottom center, as it looked the best there )
- Removed `$(".slider-large-image").css({'width' : imagereelwidth});` and added `.slider-large-image`, to make it rotate endless times.
- I edited so much, that I forgot to update every single step. Anyways, it works. And also its endless now, meaning that there is no end for the carousel.
- I wasted about 2 hours on this answer. So basically I was too lazy to compose it in the form of a plugin. [Read this](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html) and follow those steps, if you want to put it in a plugin form.
- If you want to add a function that automatically switches the slides, then use the [jQuery doTimeout: Like setTimeout, but better](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)!
- I hope you are not taking my answer in a negative form. The community guidelines actually say, that we have to point the newbies to the correct path etc etch. I actually love you man :)

**Live demo**

**http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/PmXr2/**

**Full version code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Having trouble making this product slider. Please help? - Kalle H. Väravas answer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
        html, body, div, th, td, p, a {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;}
        .cb {clear: both;}
        #wrapper {width: 400px; margin: 0px auto;}
            .main-slider {float: left; position: relative; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 0px solid #000; top: 25px; left: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 1px #999; padding: 0px; color: #FFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; /*background-color: #CCC;*/}
            .window {width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
                .slider-large-image {position: relative; overflow: hidden; float: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
                    .slider-large-image li {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; display: inline-block;}
                        .slider-large-image li img {float: left; width: 300px; height: 200px;}
            .slider-pager {position: relative; z-index: 2; margin: -40px auto 0px;}
                .slider-pager a {margin: 0px 2px; padding: 2px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; color: #ccc;}
                    .slider-pager a:hover,
                    .slider-pager a:active {background-color: #999; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;}
                    .slider-pager a:hover {color: black;}
                    .slider-pager a.active {/* background-color and border-radius used to be here.. */}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main-slider">
            <div class="window">
                <ul class="slider-large-image">
                    <li><img src="http://images.sneakhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Miley-Cyrus-300x200.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://wa2.www.3news.co.nz/Portals/0-Articles/185340/miley-cyrus_reuters_420.jpg?width=300" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://cdn.buzznet.com/media/jjr/headlines/2009/03/miley-cyrus-ryan-seacrest.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2010/12/29/2112265/miley_cyrus_400-300x200.jpg" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-pager"><a href="#" id="b">&lsaquo;</a><a href="#" id="f">&rsaquo;</a></div>
        </div>
        <br class="cb" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var imagewidth = $('.slider-large-image li').outerWidth();
        var imagesum = $('.slider-large-image li img').size();
        var imagereelwidth = imagewidth * imagesum;
        $(".slider-large-image").css({'width' : imagereelwidth});
        $('.slider-large-image li:first').before($('.slider-large-image li:last'));
        $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
        rotatef = function (imagewidth) {
            var left_indent = parseInt($('.slider-large-image').css('left')) - imagewidth;
            $('.slider-large-image:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function() {
                $('.slider-large-image li:last').after($('.slider-large-image li:first')); 
                $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
            }); 
        };
        rotateb = function (imagewidth) {
            var left_indent = parseInt($('.slider-large-image').css('left')) + imagewidth;       
            $('.slider-large-image:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function(){               
                $('.slider-large-image li:first').before($('.slider-large-image li:last')); 
                $('.slider-large-image').css({'left' : '-' + imagewidth + 'px'});
            });
        };
        $(".slider-pager a#b").click(function () {
            rotateb(imagewidth);
            return false;
        });
        $(".slider-pager a#f").click(function () {
            rotatef(imagewidth);
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,mate. But,there seems to be a problem here. The code works perfectly on jsfiddle but its not working on my pc. What could be the possible reason?
    

 <script type="text/javascript" src="products.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
     <head>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Our products</title>
     <link href="products.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     </head>

I've declared this before the body tag

Comment: Well, for the record fiddle uses 1.6 jquery. Second, what is in products.js and products.css? If you just put that jQuery script in the products.js then the problem is right there. Since this script as I noted out, is not a plugin. So it must be called AFTER the actual element. So, it must be in the footer, before </body>. If in the products.js is just that script, then simply move the <script src="products.js"> to footer, thats it.

Comment: Found out the problem! The jquery file was after products.js :S

Yea, i know. A very noobish mistake.
But,seriously man. Thanks a lot for the help and time! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh right, your correct. Anyway, if the answer was the thing you were looking for, don't forget to hit the accept button :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rotatef = function() {

$(".slider-large-image").animate({ 
"left" : "-="+imagewidth
},500 );
};

rotateb = function() {

$(".slider-large-image").animate({ 
"left": "+="+imagewidth
},500 );
};
```